# implementing SSO with azure ad nodeJS SAML

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I am trying to implement SSO with azure AD using nodeJS. I have been given some information from the person I am working with. They are basically hosting my site on their internal company site, and want to make sure they can authenticate using their company directory. the information they provided me with was from azure AD (tenantID, user access URL, application ID and object ID along with a metadata file). I found some info online about passport being a good option to use, but honestly this is my first time every implementing SSO into a site, and i'm a little lost. my code is below, please let me know if anyone has done this before.

```
 var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://myapps.microsoft.com/signin/SAML-companyname-DEV/id?tenantId=id
    issuer: 'issuer'
  },
  

  function(profile, done) {
    findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, user);
      
    });
  })
);

app.post('/login/callback',
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside /login/callback')
    //after login, goes here, but renders back to login/callback. then back here.
   res.render('login.ejs')
  }
);

app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/failed-login.ejs', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
      console.log("inside azuread /login passport saml")
     res.render('index.ejs')
  }
);


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session(
  {
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'test secret'
  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));


// 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send(err.status)
});
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial : https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/azure-ad-saml-federation-application-tutorial/ It has well articulated concept and a walkthrough of code.